# ¿Por qué el view model me llega con valores nulos luego del envío del formulario al controlador en ASP .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, vscode

**¿Cuál es el problema**

Tengo una vista que tiene un ViewModel como modelo de datos. Dentro de la vista tengo un formulario para que, al presionar el botón submit, me envíe el modelo al controlador pertinente. El problema que tengo es que cuando reviso por medio de la herramienta debugger de Visual Studio Code, el modelo se encuentra null cosa que no debería ser así.

**¿Qué he intentado para solucionarlo?**

Hay una consideración a tomar en cuenta: Probando, decidí, en vez de pasarle el view model, usar el modelo, que en este caso es la clase Productos, y me llevé la sorpresa de que cuando uso la clase Productos como modelo sí me trae los datos, pero cuando uso una clase de modelo distinta, me trae nulos los datos.

**Consideraciones**

- Estoy haciendo uso de ASP .NET Core 2.0.

  El editor de código que estoy usando es Visual Studio Code.

  Hago uso del sistema de autenticación autogenerado al momento de ejecutar el comando

  ```
  dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
  ```

  He modificado la configuración por defecto que se crea de la base de datos para hacer uso de SQL Server como SGBD.

  Soy un principiante en todos estos temas.

---

A continuación las partes del código involucradas:

## Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace CatalogoCompra.Models {
    public class Producto {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Nombre")]
        [Required, MaxLength (80)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Precio")]
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Empresa")]
        [Required, MaxLength (80)]
        public string Empresa { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Breve descripción")]
        [MaxLength (300)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Elija su foto")]
        [Required]
        public string UrlFoto { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey ("UserId")]
        [Required]
        public ApplicationUser AplicationUser { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Fecha de publicación")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime FechaPublicacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using CatalogoCompra.Models;

namespace CatalogoCompra.Models.ManageViewModels
{
    public class HomeAgregarViewModel
    {
        public IFormFile Foto;
        public Producto Producto;
    }
}
```

## View

```html
@using System
@model HomeAgregarViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Agregar Producto";
}

<!--TODO: Solucionar problema que hace que los datos lleguen nulos-->

<form method="post" asp-action="Agregar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>

    <h1>Agrega un nuevo producto</h1>

    <br/>

    <!--Nombre-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Producto.Nombre"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Producto.Nombre" placeholder="Juan">     
    </div>

    <!--Precio-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Producto.Precio"></label>
      <input type="number" asp-for="Producto.Precio" class="form-control" placeholder="$ 100000"/>
    </div>

    <!--Empresa-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Producto.Empresa"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Producto.Empresa" placeholder="Empresa">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Nombre de la empresa que provee el producto</small>
    </div>

    <!--Fecha de publicación-->
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Producto.FechaPublicacion" value="@DateTime.Today">
    
    <!--Id del usuario logueado-->
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Producto.UserId" value="">


    <!--Descripción-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Producto.Descripcion"></label>
      <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Producto.Descripcion" rows="3" placeholder="Descripción del producto"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--Foto-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Producto.UrlFoto"></label>
      <input type="file" asp-for="Foto" class="form-control-file"/>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Aquí debe poner una foto para que los demás puedan ver su producto.</small>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

## Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CatalogoCompra.Models;
using CatalogoCompra.Models.ManageViewModels;
using CatalogoCompra.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CatalogoCompra.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        private readonly UserManager _userManager;

        private IProductosData _productosData;
        private HomeIndexViewModel model;

        public HomeController (UserManager userManager, IProductosData productosData) {
            _productosData = productosData;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index () {
            model = new HomeIndexViewModel ();
            model.Productos = _productosData.GetProductos ();

            return View (model);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Agregar () {
            return View ();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task Agregar (HomeAgregarViewModel viewModel) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                ApplicationUser usuario = await GetCurrentUserAsync ();
                var producto = viewModel.Producto;
                var Foto = viewModel.Foto;

                // Guardando foto de perfil en servidor.
                var path = Path.Combine (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory (), "wwwroot/img/", usuario.Id, Foto.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Create)) {
                    await Foto.CopyToAsync (stream);
                }

                producto.UrlFoto = "img/" + Foto.FileName; // Él sabe que debe guardar en wwwroot porque así se lo indiqué al momento de inyectar el FileProvider.
                producto.UserId = usuario?.Id; // Evluando si hay usuario o no. Si hay, entonces almacenar su Id en el campo producto.UserId.

                // Guardando datos del usuario en el servidor.
                _productosData.AddProducto (producto);

                return RedirectToAction ("Index");
            } else {
                return View (this.model);
            }
        }

        private Task GetCurrentUserAsync () => _userManager.GetUserAsync (HttpContext.User);

        public IActionResult Contact () {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";
            return View ();
        }

        public IActionResult Error () {
            return View (new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta que te dieron? De ser así, acéptala para colaborar con la salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes par de errores pero no es nada grave. En primer lugar en tu viewmodel tienes que cambiar esto:

```
public class HomeAgregarViewModel
{
    public IFormFile Foto;
    public Producto Producto;
}
```

por esto:

```
public class HomeAgregarViewModel:Producto
{
    public IFormFile Foto;
}
```

Por qué este cambio? Esto es debido a que de la forma en que lo tenías declarado anteriormente estabas estableciendo una propiedad de navegación para Producto a lo que se traduce como que un HomeAgregarViewModel tiene un producto y podrías llamarlo de la forma: HomeAgregarViewModel.Producto.Atributoquesea y esto no es lo que necesitas. Lo que necesitas es crear un viewmodel para generar un formulario basado en un modelo, por eso al heredar de Producto ya tu viewmodel adquiere todos los atributos de la clase Producto. Esto requiere que hagas un cambio en tu vista puesto que en los campos del formulario no puedes preguntar por el Producto.Atributo sino por el atributo en si ya que estas utilizando el viewmodel como modelo. ejemplo:

```
@using System
@model HomeAgregarViewModel

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Agregar Producto";
}

<!--TODO: Solucionar problema que hace que los datos lleguen nulos-->

<form method="post" asp-action="Agregar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>

        <h1>Agrega un nuevo producto</h1>

        <br />

        <!--Nombre-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Nombre"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Nombre" placeholder="Juan">
        </div>

        <!--Precio-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Precio"></label>
            <input type="number" asp-for="Precio" class="form-control" placeholder="$ 100000" />
        </div>

        <!--Empresa-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Empresa"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Empresa" placeholder="Empresa">
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Nombre de la empresa que provee el producto</small>
        </div>

        //Esto puedes eliminarlo
        <!--Fecha de publicación-->
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="FechaPublicacion" value="@DateTime.Today">
        //Esto puedes eliminarlo
        <!--Id del usuario logueado-->
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId" value="">


        <!--Descripción-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Descripcion"></label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Descripcion" rows="3" placeholder="Descripción del producto"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!--Foto-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Foto"></label>
            <input type="file" name="Foto" class="form-control-file" />
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Aquí debe poner una foto para que los demás puedan ver su producto.</small>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
@await  Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
}
```

Otra parte a modificar es tu Modelo, ya que Producto.cs tiene algunas validaciones que no cecesitas y otras que te podrían levantar errores de validación. recuerda que al usar un ViewModel estás pasadno el mismo como modelo al formulario por lo que las validaciones se le aplicarían al ViewModel y no a tu modelo pero en este ejemplo como heredamos de Producto se pueden dejar las validaciones en tu clase Producto que el ViewModel las cogerá. ejemplo:

```
 public class Producto
{   //EF reconoce por defecto Id como llave y lo establece como Not Null por lo que Required y Key están de más     
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [Required, MaxLength(80)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Precio")]
    [Required]//Esto si debería ser Not Null
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
    [Required, MaxLength(80)]
    public string Empresa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Breve descripción")]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    // Aqui tenías puesto Required esto no puede ser porque tu estableces
    // la ruta en el controlador después de enviar el formulario por lo que 
    // pasaría null desde la vista y al tener Required nunca sería válido el formulario
    public string UrlFoto { get; set; }

    //Aqui es lo mismo que con UrlFoto debes eliminar el Required
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de publicación")]
    public DateTime FechaPublicacion { get; set; }
}
```

y al final unos pequeños cambios en tu controlador

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Agregar(HomeAgregarViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUser usuario = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);


            // Guardando foto de perfil en servido
            //toda tu logica para guardar fotos

            var producto = new Producto()
            {
                Nombre = viewModel.Nombre,
                Precio = viewModel.Precio,
                Empresa = viewModel.Empresa,
                FechaPublicacion = DateTime.Today,
                Descripcion = viewModel.Descripcion,
                UserId = usuario.Id,
                UrlFoto = //Aqui va la ruta de tu foto
            };

            // Guardando datos del usuario en el servidor.
            _context.Add(producto);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }            
            return View();            
    }
```

en el controlador declara:

```
Usermanager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

para que lo llames después a la hora de recoger el Id del Usuario. En este ejemplo yo utilicé el contexto por defecto pero igual puedes seguir llamando tu contexto. Lo interesante es a la hora de crear el producto que cambian un poco las cosas, recuerda que estas pasando un viewmodel desde la vista, por lo que debes crear una instancia de Producto y llenar sus parámetros a partir de los recogidos en el viewmodel. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto me paso algo parecido

```
ModelState.Clear();
```